# Handle dynamically growing list in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component for displaying a list, and this component is rendered from a parent component. I am currently generating the contents of this list using a for loop. Like -

```
let content = []
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  content.push(
    <div>
      <p> list[i].something </p>
      <p> list[i].somethingElse </p>
    </div>
  )
}

return content;
```

Now whenever a new object is added to this list, all the previous objects of the list, and the newly added object get rendered. This becomes extremely slow when the list contains around 1000 objects.

Is there a way by which only the new added can be added and rendered, without re-rendering all the previous entries of the list again?

Comment: Hi! Can you give us a more complete example of what you're doing with `content`? Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This must be mainly because you havent added `key`, try the following code after setting an id for each list item and assign it to key prop.

```
let content = []
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  content.push(
    <div key={list[i].id}>
      <p> list[i].something </p>
      <p> list[i].somethingElse </p>
    </div>
  )
}

return content;
```

If the list is a static one which doesnt change, index can also be used as the value for key prop.

```
let content = []
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  content.push(
    <div key={i}>
      <p> list[i].something </p>
      <p> list[i].somethingElse </p>
    </div>
  )
}

return content;
```

Comment: In that case as I mentioned you can use the unique id for each item as the value for key prop instead of `i`.

Comment: If the list is a static list which doesnt change, using index is of no harm. And the reason i cant give `key={id}` in the answer is that there is no specification about an available `id` in the question.

Comment: Something like the changed answer :) ?

Comment: Yeah, although I'd probably say "Have a unique `id`," not **if** you have a unique `id`, and show how to have one if they don't already (always-increasing number, whatever).

Answer (score 1):

You shoulda unique id for each item to render list item component. You can do on the ES6 something like:

```
const renderList = (list) => (
 list.map(item =>
  <div key={item.id}>
   <p>{item.something}</p>
   <p>{item.somethingElse}</p>
  </div>
);
```